# In-App Billing v3: queryInventoryAsync returns 0 items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I know this question is asked multiple times on stackoverflow but seem to be not have any answers satisfy to me.

I implement in-app billing V3 for my application and try to follow the **TriviaDrive** sample app from documentation page.

My app has published on google play for years with many Managed Product are activated to be available for any purchases from users

Since v3 I got stack at step query inventory, the code is:

```
mIaHelper.queryInventoryAsync(new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {

                    // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                    if (mIaHelper == null) return;

                    LOGD(TAG, "query inventory failed:" + result.getMessage());
                    // Is it a failure?
                    if (result.isFailure()) {
//                        complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                        return;
                    }
}
});
```

The **result** is succeded but the Inventory inv return 0 items, so I cannot get pennding purchase to continue consuming that purchase

I also signed my app and published to alpha channel with a group persons of tester, but seem everything stop at that step, can anyone help me?